# The Saxon word "Scop" as in "bard."

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english, germanic-languages, old-norse

Old & Middle English/Germanic Languages–Scholars, please help.

I'm interested in any information you might share on all senses of the Saxon word "[Scop](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scop)," meaning "Bard" or "Poet," including its pronunciation throughout the transitions between Old and Middle English as well as its etymology including "Skald" and most specifically, if anyone can speak to whether it is related to "Smith" in the sense we mean in constructions such as "blacksmith" or "wordsmith?"— something I vaguely recall from a lecture by Prof. Joseph Baird, in his "History of the English Language."  I have not been able to substantiate this recollection through any authoritative source, although I have admittedly limited access to the OED online and little training in this regard.

Comment: You say you have "limited access" to the OED. Have you read its entries *smith* and *scop*? Because that is likely to be the main source. Etymology further back than Proto Germanic seems unknown. It might also help if you refined the question to be more specific.

Comment: I've always suspected that *scop* might carry with it the meaning of *seer* or *watcher*. This is because the OE word for bishop (*biscop* or *bisceop*) ultimately comes from Greek *episkopos* meaning, roughly *overseer* or *overwatcher*. It's most likely a folk etymology, but I find it interesting.

Comment: From the ***full*** (subscription-only) OED: *Origin: A word **inherited from Germanic**.
Etymology: Old English **scop , sceop** = Old High German **scoph , scof** (masculine), cognate with Old High German **scoph** (? neuter) poetry, fiction (‘commentum’), sport, jest, derision (‘ludibrium’), Old Norse **skop** railing, mocking: see **scoff** n.*

Comment: @StuartF, I have in the distant past but as FumbleFingers points out, the full version of the OED is subscription only.  I have not been able to get to a library to access the subscription version since my interest in the term was revived more recently, but I absolutely will search on "Smith" as well, which may not have occurred to me without your helpful suggestion.  Additionally, I wonder if there is an entry for some combination of "scop" along with a term that is coupled with "smith" such as "blacksmith" in the form "blackscop."  I was never aware of the pejorative sense "scoff," to mock

Comment: @Robusto - Love the association with "seer" or "watcher" as that would add richness to the meaning I'm looking for as one who "shapes" or "oversees" the form as a "blacksmith" shapes the iron or media with which they work.  The sense as "smith" may well be what you call "folk" etymology, as well, since there is certainly no abundance of content resultant from a Google search or a cursory exploration of the main terms.  Old Professor Baird was a rather erudite fellow, thus; I don't think he'd have fabricated a relation in absence of rigorous, historical underpinnings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for the clip from the full version of the OED.  I haven't looked into subscribing in many years, but at the very least a trip to the public library is warranted.  I was not aware of the more pejorative sense of "sport, derision, mocking," which is interesting and in the more playful sense of "jest" adds richness, where in the more sinister sense of "mocking, railing, or derision, probably detracts somewhat from my purposes.  Your parenthetical additions offer auspicious jumping off points for further exploration.  Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what can be extracted from the SOED (*Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*).

> (SOED) **scop** /ʃɒp, skɒp/ n [OE *sćop sćeop* = OHG *scof*, *scopf*, poet, ON *skop*, mocking, railing cf. SCOFF n¹] *Hist.* A poet or minstrel during the Anglo-Saxon period.
> Obs after ME; revived in L18.

Surprisingly, the combination "sc" in this word can be pronounced either /ʃ/ or /sk/. It goes back to Old English (OE), a type of English that extends roughly from 700 to 1100. It is the word for "poet", and it is found  also in Old High German (OHG) in the form "*scof*" and  "*scopf*"; the Old Norse word  "*skop*", of the same family means however "mocking", "railing". It became obsolete after 1350 (end of ME). It was revived in the period between 1770 and 1800 (L18).

> (SOED) **scoff** ME [Perh. of Scand. origin Cf. early modern Danish *skof*, *skuf*, jest, mockery, *skuffe*, mock, jest, also (as now) deceive, disappoint, related to Old Frisian *skof*, mockery, OHG *skof*, *skopf* poet Cf. scop.]
> **1a** Contemptuous ridicule, scorn, mockery. Now *rare* or *obsolete*. **b** A taunt, an expression of scorn or mockery. L16.
> **2** An object of contempt, ridicule or scorn. L17.

Comment: Thank you!  I have heard both pronunciations and both seemed to be authoritative sources, so I'm happy to learn both are correct.  I wonder if the pronunciation changed as a result of one of the great "shifts" over time.  The material from the OED is much appreciated.